# How to get elements with specific values in a XML using regular expression?

Tags: python, regex, xml

I have this piece of xml string.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xmi:XMI xmi:version="2.0" xmlns:xmi="http://www.omg.org/XMI" xmlns:libraries="http://www.ibm.com/websphere/appserver/schemas/5.0/libraries.xmi">
  <libraries:Library xmi:id="Library_1382473016602" name="sfi_lib" isolatedClassLoader="false">
    <classPath>${HOME_SFI_LIB}/sfi_com_sqw_java.jar</classPath>
  </libraries:Library>
  <libraries:Library xmi:id="Library_1528914932212" name="sfi_lib_server" isolatedClassLoader="false">
    <classPath>${HOME_SFI_LIB}/jasper/jasperreports-5.6.0.jar</classPath>
    <classPath>${HOME_SFI_LIB}/jasper/jasperreports-fonts-3.7.4.jar</classPath>
    <classPath>${HOME_SFI_LIB}/commons/commons-beanutils-1.8.2.jar</classPath>
    <classPath>${HOME_SFI_LIB}/commons/commons-collections-3.2.1.jar</classPath>
    <classPath>${HOME_SFI_LIB}/commons/commons-digester-2.1.jar</classPath>
    <classPath>${HOME_SFI_LIB}/commons/commons-discovery-0.2.jar</classPath>
    <classPath>${HOME_SFI_LIB}/commons/commons-logging-1.1.1.jar</classPath>
    <classPath>${HOME_SFI_LIB}/commons/xml-apis.jar</classPath>
    <classPath>${HOME_SFI_LIB}/commons/iText-2.1.7.jar</classPath>
    <classPath>${HOME_SFI_LIB}/jasper/barbecue-1.5-beta1.jar</classPath>
    <classPath>${HOME_SFI_LIB}/bouncycastle/bcprov-jdk15-1.45.jar</classPath>
    <classPath>${HOME_SFI_LIB}/bouncycastle/bcmail-jdk15-1.45.jar</classPath>
    <classPath>${HOME_SFI_LIB}/bouncycastle/bctsp-jdk14-1.45.jar</classPath>
    <classPath>${HOME_SFI}/sfi_arquivos/templates</classPath>
    <classPath>${HOME_SFI_LIB}/sfi_framework_java.jar</classPath>
    <classPath>${HOME_SFI_LIB}/sfi_adm_ama_java.jar</classPath>
    <classPath>${HOME_SFI_LIB}/sfi_adm_gce_java.jar</classPath>
    <classPath>${HOME_SFI_LIB}/sfi_adm_gdl_java.jar</classPath>
    <classPath>${HOME_SFI_LIB}/sfi_adm_prt_java.jar</classPath>
    <classPath>${HOME_SFI_LIB}/sfi_com_acg_java.jar</classPath>
    <classPath>${HOME_SFI_LIB}/sfi_com_sca_java.jar</classPath>
    <classPath>${HOME_SFI_LIB}/sfi_com_tge_java.jar</classPath>
    <classPath>${HOME_SFI_LIB}/sfi_com_utl_java.jar</classPath>
    <classPath>${HOME_SFI_LIB}/sfi_ext_sge_java.jar</classPath>
  </libraries:Library>
</xmi:XMI>
```

What I'm trying to do is get the values of the elements that starts with `${HOME_SFI_LIB}/sfi_`.
I'm using `re` python's module to do the work. My current code is filtering only by tag `classPath`, but is not enough. The regular expression I'm currently using:

```
re.findall('<classPath>(.*?)</classPath>', xml)
```

Can someone help me to improve my RE in order to filter the elements that starts with `${HOME_SFI_LIB}/sfi_`, like the node `<classPath>${HOME_SFI_LIB}/sfi_adm_gce_java.jar</classPath>`?

Comment: XML and regex are not good friends. Use a parser, it is simpler, faster and much more maintainable.

Comment: @Toto while I agree the linked post directly *addresses* the question, I wouldn't go so far as to say it *answers* it. There are probably better duplicates for the python-specific use case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags) famously points out, it is better to use an xml parser such as `lxml` to browse languages such as xml, html, and xhtml:

```py
from lxml import etree

with open('your_file.xml') as fh:
    tree = etree.parse(fh)

# Now you have an elementTree instance that you can search tags with
# we can use a selector here to return a list
class_paths = tree.xpath('//classPath')

for c in class_paths:
    if '${HOME_SFI_LIB}/sfi_' in c.text:
        # rest of your code
```

While you could argue that for a simple xml doc, a regex approach can work, in general, trees make this process much easier to extend to larger and more complicated documents

### Edit

If you can't `pip install lxml`, the [`xml`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#module-xml.etree.ElementTree) package is built in and functions in a fairly similar fashion

```py
from xml.etree import ElementTree as ET

with open('your_file.xml') as fh:
    tree = ET.parse(fh)

for element in tree.iterfind('.//classPath'):
    if '${HOME_SFI_LIB}/sfi_' in element.text:
        # rest of your code
```

Comment: The problem is: I can't install any lib in the server I'm working. That's why I'm trying to do using pure python

Comment: Then the `xml.etree` package should do nicely, it's a builtin. i'll edit my answer